# Measurability of $T \to \Pi_{ker T}$ w.r.t. SOT

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I came across the following technical question, to which I could not - after some time of thinking - find an answer:

Let $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{H}$ be two real (in general infinite dimensional) separable Hilbert spaces. For some linear subspace $\bar{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$, let $\Pi_U$ denote the orthogonal projection on this subspace. The question is:

Is the mapping $T \mapsto \Pi_{\text{ker}T}$ measurable from $L(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{H})$ to $L(\mathcal{U})$ when both spaces are endowed with the strong operator topology (and measurability is meant w.r.t. the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra of the SOT on both sides)?

Any hints and thoughts on this are more than appreciated!

Comment: can you write the projection as $lim 1 - (T^*T)^{\frac 1 n}$, and therefore the limit of continuous funtions ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I can't work your argument out. Would appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like the answer below does that

Comment: I (partially) agree. However, how do you deal with the two questions I added below?

Answer (score 3):

It is true if you consider the unit ball. (Which should be sufficient because $\Pi_{\ker(\lambda T)} = \Pi_{\ker(T)}$ for all $\lambda\neq 0$.)

Also note that $\ker(T) = \ker(T^\ast T)$. I will therefore restrict my attention to normal operators $T$. That may or may not be sufficient for the application you have in mind.

Then we have $\Pi_{\ker(T)} = 1_{\{0\}}(T)$, where we use the measurable functional calculus.

If we define $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} (1-|x|)^n & |x|\leq 1 \\ 0 & |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$ we have a sequence continuous, uniformly bounded functions on $\mathbb{C}$ with $f_n\to 1_{\{0\}}$ pointwise. Therefore $f_n(T) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{s.o.t} 1_{\{0\}}(T)$.

It is therefore sufficient to prove that $B_1(L(U))_{sot} \to L(U)_{sot}, T\mapsto f(T)$ is continuous for all continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$. If $T_i\xrightarrow{s.o.t} T$ and $x\in U$ arbitrary, then approximate $f$ uniformly on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|\leq1\}$ by some polynomial $p$. Now remember that $p(X)-p(Y) = \tilde{p}(X,Y)(X-Y)$ for some polynomial $\tilde{p}$ of degree $\deg(p)-1$ and that $\mathbb{D}$ contains $\sigma(T)$ for all $T\in B_1(L(U))$ so that:

$\begin{align*}
\|f(T)x-f(S)x\| &\leq \|p(T)x-p(S)x\| + 2\epsilon\|x\| \\
&\leq \|\tilde{p}(T,S)\cdot (T-S)x\| + \epsilon\|x\| \\
&\leq const\|(T-S)x\| + 2\epsilon\|x\|
\end{align*}$

Now if $T\xrightarrow{s.o.t}S$, then this proves $\forall\epsilon>0: \limsup_{T\to S} \|f(T)x-f(S)x\|\leq 2\epsilon\|x\|$ to that $f(T)\xrightarrow{s.o.t}f(S)$.

Comment: How does non-measurability follow from that?

Comment: It doesn't. I thought you asked about continuity.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have no experience with measurable functional calculus, so right now I cannot follow all of your arguments. However, I see your general line of argument on how to obtain the measurability. But intuitively: Concerning the reduction to the unit ball, isn't it a problem that the constant $\lambda$ can certainly not be chosen independent of $T$? Wouldn't you need to be able to push an arbitrary open set of $L(U,H)$ into the unit ball?

Comment: Why do the weak and strong operator topology coincide on bounded sets of $L(U,H)$, $L(H,U)$ respectively? I could neither prove this myself nor find a source, which states this statement. Can you help me out on this?

Comment: You're right. I misremembered that one. The true statement is that the weak and ultraweak topology agree on bounded sets as do the strong and ultrastrong. The weak and the strong are still different as evidenced by the fact that the adjoint is continuous w.r.t. the weak, but not the strong topology. So that's a hole in my argument. One has to assume $T$ to be normal to make the rest of proof go through. Depending on the application you have in mind, that may still be enough.

Comment: What I actually want is this: I read a paper on SPDEs in which the following situation appears: We are given a map $\sigma: \mathbb{R}_+ \times \Omega \to L(U,H)$, where $\Omega$ is a probability space and $U, H$ are separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. We assume that $\sigma$ is (w.r.t. a given filtration on $\Omega$) predictable w.r.t. the SOT on $L(U,H)$. Then it is assumed without any comment that also $(t,\omega) \mapsto \Pi_{\text{ker}\sigma(t,\omega)}$ is predictable, again w.r.t. the SOT (this time, of course, on $L(U)$). The statement I asked for would certainly imply this.

Comment: In particular, I don't think that I can w.l.o.g. restrict my attention to normal operators.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but could you also elaborate why it suffices to take the unit ball on $L(U,H)$? My idea was: If the preimage of $T \to \Pi_{\text{ker}T}$ of any subbase element of SOT in $L(U)$ was bd. in $L(U,H)$, then one could (?) squeeze it into the unit ball through a small constant. But I could not make this contraction precise - intuitively, one would rather have to do it the other way around, i.e. "compress" it before taking the inverse and then blow it up. But this seems to be unprecise. Also, I don't think that any subbase element has bounded inverse or am I wrong here?

Comment: The issue with the scaling can be taken care of by the following argument: norm $||T||$ is measurable, so you first consider the map $T \mapsto \frac{T}{\exp(||T||)}$ and then run the proof in the bounded case. As for the second issue, I don't know if that helps, but it suffices to prove SOT to WOT measurability as WOT and SOT coincide on the set of projections.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Mateusz! I don't think considering SOT-WOT-measurability will fix the issue. The (begin of the) idea developed above is to rewrite $T\mapsto\Pi_{\text{ker}T}$ as $T\mapsto (T^*,T)\mapsto T^*T\mapsto\Pi_{\text{ker}T^*T}$. The final mapping (which determines the topology we can choose for the state space of $T \mapsto\Pi_{\text{ker}T}$) is (when considering selfadjoint op. only) clearly SOT-SOT (by the Borel functional calculus). The issue is $T \mapsto(T^*,T)$, in particular $T \mapsto T^*$. I think we cannot afford less than SOT-SOT-continuity here. Any thoughts?